# store data in an empty data.frame in R with character

Tags: r, dataframe, character

i have an empty data.frame

```
write.df <- data.frame(Title=character(),
                Date=character(),
                Type=character(),
                NoDataPer=numeric(),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

where i need to store the result during a loop

```
for(i in 1:5){
     #do some stuff
     write.df[i,] <- data.frame(MyTitle,MyDate,MyType,MyNoDataPer)
}
```

when i see the data.frame i got this instead of the character values

```
> write.df
  Title Date Type NoDataPer
1     1    1    1      95.8
2     1    1    1      96.9
3     1    1    1      99.6
4     1    1    1      61.8
5     1    1    1      60.5
```

where `Title`, `Date`, and `Type` are for example `MYD11A1_2012.06.07.LST_Night_1km`, `2012-06-07`, and `Night`

Answer (score 1):

writing

```
write.df[i,] <- list(raster_name,date_r,type,NANvalidPER)
```

instead of

```
write.df[i,] <- data.frame(raster_name,date_r,type,NANvalidPER)
```

i got the right write.df

```
write.df
                             Title       Date  Type NoDataPer
1   MYD11A1_2012.03.01.LST_Day_1km 2012-03-01   Day      95.8
2   MYD11A1_2012.06.06.LST_Day_1km 2012-06-06   Day      96.9
3 MYD11A1_2012.06.06.LST_Night_1km 2012-06-06 Night      99.6
4   MYD11A1_2012.06.07.LST_Day_1km 2012-06-07   Day      61.8
5 MYD11A1_2012.06.07.LST_Night_1km 2012-06-07 Night      60.5
```